# plotly express reorders categorical x-axis scatter if I add a color

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Imagine I have a set of observations, ordered in rows. Each observation has quantitative and ordinal measurements associated with it.

The observations are ordered based on a quantitative measurement (ie order is important), but because order not magnitude matters in that dimension I want to use a categorical x axis scatter instead of a numerical x axis scatter.

This all works fine *as long as* I don't add a 'color' to the plotly express scatter:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
metrics = ['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4']
a = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'b']
b = [1,2,3,4]
c = [4,5,6,7]
d = ['w','x','y','z']
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[a,b,c,d], index=metrics).T
```

The above code will generate a plotly chart where the observations are plotted in the order they are found in the dataframe:
`px.scatter(data, y='m2', x='m4')`.

[correct ordering of datapoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8CcC.png)

However, if I add a color, via `px.scatter(data, y='m2', x='m4', color='m1')`, the *order* is jumbled up!

[incorrect ordering of datapoints if i add a color/hue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF2vq.png)

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter 'category_order', and pass a dictionary in the dimension you want to specify order: eg in this case add parameter `category_orders={'m4':d}`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this worked for me:

```
fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder='category ascending')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).